# Definition of DateInterval's given period's roll-over-point

Tags: php, dateinterval

From [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)'s official documentation, it mentions that:

> The specification can also be represented as a date time. A sample of one year and four days would be P0001-00-04T00:00:00. But the values in this format can not exceed a given period's roll-over-point (e.g. 25 hours is invalid).

What is the meaning of roll-over-point?

Here is a simple test:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT1000M')); // no problem
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT100000M')); // no problem
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT10000000M')); // no problem
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT1000000000M')); // no problem
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT100000000000M')); // no problem
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT10000000000000M')); // exception
```

The exception is:

> Caught exception: DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (PT10000000000000M)

So, what is the maximum value of minutes to be added?